# FB JS SDK: FB.Login callback fired twice on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a strange problem implementing the JS FB-SDK. Everything is working flawless except in IE 11. The method `FB.login` of the [official JS API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v3.3), which receives a callback, is firing it twice after the OAuth dialog pops up and the user authorizes the application. The first time it returns a response with the parameter `authResponse` as undefined, the second time it has all the expected values.

I have absolutely no clue as to why this is happening. I've double and triple checked that `FB.login` is not called twice anywhere. Did anyone ever overcome this scenario or made FB login work with IE ?

It works perfect in Edge, Firefox, Chrome and even mobile browsers: chrome and safari in iOS, Android Chrome.

I'm providing a minimal reproducible code demo.

```
### index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FB IE 11</title>
</head>

<body> 
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <button
    id="fblogin">
    Sign in with Facebook
  </button>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js'></script>
    <script  src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
### script.js

(function($) {

  var EP = { facebook: {} }

  EP.facebook.init_was_called = false;
  EP.facebook.promise = $.Deferred();
  EP.facebook.connected = false;
  EP.facebook.emailDeclined = false;
  EP.facebook.loginRetryCount = 0;

  window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
    console.log("window.fbAsyncInit callback triggered by Facebook SDK");
    window.FB.init({
      appId: "418117192377109", // should be your app id when testing
      cookie: true, // Store fbsr_xxx cookie
      xfmbl: false,
      version: "v3.2",
      status: true // Fetch user's facebook login status
    });
    EP.facebook.promise.resolve();
  };

  // Use this to wrap any calls where we're not sure the FB api has been bootstrapped
  EP.facebook.afterFacebookInitialized = callback => {
    return $.when(EP.facebook.promise).then(callback);
  };

  $(function() {
    // Always parseFBML
    EP.facebook.afterFacebookInitialized().done(function() {
      window.FB.XFBML.parse();
    });

    if (EP.facebook.init_was_called) {
      return;
    }
    EP.facebook.init_was_called = true;

    // This only needs to be called once per full page load (on The Post and when showing login screen)
    $.getScript("https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js");
  });

  var Facebook = function() {
      var fbLoginParams;

      if (!window.FB) {
        console.log('FB not loaded yet!')
        return;
      } else if (EP.facebook.connected && !EP.facebook.emailDeclined) {
        console.log('Already logged in to FB')
        return;
      } else {
        fbLoginParams = {
          scope: "email"
        };
        if (EP.facebook.emailDeclined) {
          fbLoginParams.auth_type = "rerequest";
        }
        return window.FB.login(function(response) {
          console.log("FB.login response: ", response);
          if (response.authResponse) {
            EP.facebook.connected = true;
            return
          } else {
            return;
          }
        }, fbLoginParams);
      }
    }

    $("#fblogin").on("click", Facebook)
})(jQuery)
```

In order for this to work, it must be served from a server, with a domain different than *localhost* due to fb app's restrictions and served through https. I used [ngrok](http://ngrok.io) to map an https url to my local dev server. The local dev server was simply [parcel](https://parceljs.org/), started by doing `parcel build index.html` and then `parcel index.html`. Of course you need to have a developer FB app configured with a valid OAuth redirect uri (the ngrok one). Remeber also that you must be logged out from fb before testing this. This are the results after signing in to FB and authorizing the test FB app:

[image]

There they are, the 2 responses, magnificent!

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with only the above code. I try to compile the coffeescript code to javascript code but it gets error. Please provide more codes related to the issue including html codes, scripts, polyfills and so on. You can refer to this to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @YuZhou will try to build a reproducible example and come back with it!

Comment: @YuZhou There you go, see my edits. Hope this minimal example works for you. Tried to use codesandbox but does not work with IE11 so... left me no choice other than pasting the minimal code needed with minor instructions on how to try to reproduce the environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a bug in facebook! I posted in their error report help center, described the issue, and they have fixed it. The resolution is in spanish but you can check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/642726372872639/)

Of course they didn't specify the cause of the issue, but tested now and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the issue in my side. After using fiddler to compare the network traffic between IE and other browsers, I find that the login step will direct to a link-> `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/close_window/?app_id=xxxxxxxxx&connect=0` in IE11. You can see this page flash across when login in IE:
[image]
This will not happen in other browsers. I think this is the cause of two responses. This might be some issue with IE or the API is designed like this in IE.

Comment: Can you think of a workaround to ignore the first response from the example code, considering that it's very similar to the same response that happens when the user rejects authorization or dismisses the dialog without given access?

Comment: The only workaround I can figure out is to put the `console.log("FB.login response: ", response);` after `if (response.authResponse) {`, then the response only occurs when successfully connected.

Comment: Hmm that won't cut it. The thing is, that in a higher layer, I'm wrapping this in promises and when an undefined response comes in, which is the case sometimes for closed dialogs in purpose by user, I reject the promise and certain business logic triggers which impacts UI. IE 11 users will never be able to connect or see a consistent UI since the promise was already rejected despite a second response coming in